# How Much Content Should You Put on Power BI Desktop Tabs

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

I am using Power BI Embedded. I have created a .pbix file containing a few tabs worth of visualizations. Each tab contains a TimeLine visualization so I can select timer periods along with several charts and maps.

This arrangement looks good in Power BI Desktop. When I publish the .pbix file to the Power BI website, each tab can be pinned to a dashboard. Pinning a dozen visualizations does not seem to make much sense and seems to suggest that the real idea behind it is to not have many visualizations on each tab and allow the user to pin the visuals they are really interested in. The Power BI presentations I've seen also seems to do this.

My report would end up with dozens of tabs which could get very unwieldy in Power BI Desktop. Is there a right way to go about this? Is there some guidance from Microsoft or a few examples I can look at? How does this affect Power BI Embedded?

Also posted to the [Power BI Forums](http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-Much-Content-Should-You-Put-on-Power-BI-Desktop-Tabs/m-p/73293#U73293).

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I don't find multiple tabs to be that unwieldy. Of course, it boils down to personal preference/the preference of your audience. It sounds like you have things arranged nicely. 
The Power BI Showcase has some good examples of aesthetically pleasing reports [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-BI-Showcase/bd-p/PBIShowcase).

About embedding: from my personal experience, tabs do not show up when embedding a PowerBI dashboard/report in a web application.